# cost function which does not have a min/max point

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, loss-functions, decision-theory

In machine learning, is it meaningful to have a cost function which does not have a min/max point, i.e., the cost function's min/max point is negative/positive infinity? Any examples?

Answer (score 2):

One example is the so-called **death penalty** in optimization where infeasible solutions, or constraints, are handled with infinite penalty so to be easily discarded by the optimization algorithm. For example, you want to estimate positive-valued parameter using a black-box optimizer that searches for optimal value over real line. One way to tell your optimizer that it should not consider negative values is to give them infinite penalty, so that *any* non-negative outcome will be better then negative one. This may not be the best and most efficient way of dealing with such cases, but it is one of the possible approaches, especially if you do not have any other way of defineing constraints. Check *[Modern Optimization with R](https://books.google.pl/books?id=HDVxBAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Modern%20Optimization%20with%20R&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=death%20penalty&f=false)* by Paulo Cortez, or [here](https://books.google.pl/books?id=xxxJCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA18&lpg=PA18&dq=death%20penalty%20optimization%20loss&source=bl&ots=WFahLjHw4t&sig=TgfE6lrxC4LGFg-Aqm4GkZ2rMTE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1kYDM8dDPAhXCZpoKHTveDxUQ6AEIIjAD#v=onepage&q=death%20penalty%20optimization%20loss&f=false).

Comment: For an example of your example, the logarithmic scoring rule for probabilistic classification gives an infinitely bad score to predicted probabilities of 1 or 0 when the event fails to happen or does happen, respectively.

Comment: Does your example give infinitely good and infinitely bad scores? That was OP's question

Comment: @Aksakal it gives infinite penalty. It does not give both, but as I understand, the question is about giving it's about min *or* max scores. By definition loss function cannot be negative, so there can't be infinite loss.

Comment: The log score function still has a minimum though.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have an optimization problem

\begin{equation}
 \begin{array}{*2{>{\displaystyle}r}}
 \mbox{minimize (over $x$)} & c(x) \\
 \mbox{subject to} & x \in X \end{array}
\end{equation}

- A cost function that goes to infinity is perfectly reasonable. One can model infeasible choices as infinite cost choices.

  - Example: Sure I can buy a spaceship that travels to Alpha Centurai! But the cost is $+\infty$
  - Define $\hat{c}(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cl} c(x) &\text{ if } x \in X \\+\infty & \text{if } x \notin X \end{array}\right\}$ . Original problem is equivalent to minimize $\hat{c}(x)$
- A cost function $c$ that is unbounded below on the feasible set $X$ is problematic and bizarre. If an infimum does not exist on the feasible set, you probably have done something strange in formulating your problem.

---

Update: If your cost function is an expectation of some kind of sub-cost function, eg. $c(x) = \int f(x) dP$ then $c$ can still be bounded below even if $f$ is not bounded below over regions of no-support (or perhaps other $-\infty$ times 0 like technical conditions). Questions on existence of a minimum or existence of an infimum are approached far more rigorously in real analysis textbooks, optimization books etc....

Comment: I'm not sure it implies no solution, because your solution is some kind of an expectation $\int c(x)f(x)dx$, where $c(x)$ function and $f(x)$ - density. If the infinitely good score's probability is very low, then you may still get an optimum

Comment: @Aksakal Let $\hat{c}(x) = \int_{s \in S} c(x,s) f(s) ds$. Is $c$ the cost function or $\hat{c}$? Sure, that $c(x,s)$ goes off to $-\infty$ somewhere does not imply that $\hat{c}$ is unbounded below on $x \in X$. Since minimizing expected cost is commonly done, you have an important point, but at the same time, $\hat{c}$ imho is really the cost function.

Comment: Ok, I was assuming in your notation $c(x,s)$ is a loss/cost function and $\hat c$ - expected loss/cost. That's how it is in forecasting e.g. [here](http://www.faculty.ucr.edu/~taelee/paper/lossfunctions.pdf)